# ARM Cortex A-53 must have NEON technology, but it is not enabled

Tags: arm, neon, cortex-a

I want to run a NEON assembly code on Hikey board which is equipped with ARM Cortex-A53. When I want to compile my code I've got:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mfpu=neon'
```

and when I checked `/proc/cpuinfo` I got:

```
Processor   : AArch64 Processor rev 3 (aarch64)
processor   : 0
processor   : 1
processor   : 2
processor   : 3
processor   : 4
processor   : 5
processor   : 6
processor   : 7
Features    : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: AArch64
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 3

Hardware    : HiKey Development Board
```

As you can see, in the features there is no neon feature available, however when I checked [ARM specs](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a53-processor.php), Cortex-A53 is NEON capable. Does anybody know what is it all about?

Comment: [GCC AArch64 Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AArch64-Options.html#AArch64-Options) - note how, just like it's telling you, `-mfpu` is not among them.

Comment: @Notlikethat So how am I supposed to add neon features on AArch64?

Comment: Unless possibly you've built your own GCC with a crazy configuration, it's enabled by default - see the feature modifiers section.

Comment: got it, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Ah, I also realise that I read this taking entirely for granted something which might not be so familiar to everyone - "Advanced SIMD" is of course the official architectural name for the thing commonly known as "NEON".